# Refactor a foreach with if - else if structure to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have this foreach loop:

```
var includedElements = new HashSet<int>();
foreach(var e in elements)
{
    var include = false;
    if(isTable(e.Key))
    {
        if(tables.ContainsKey(e.Key)
        {
            if(tables[e.Key].Elements
               .Any(subElem => shouldBeIncluded(subElem.Key) ) )
            {
                include = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(shouldBeIncluded(e.Key))
    {
        include = true;
    }
    if(include){
        includedElements.Add(e.Key);
        DoSomeMoreStuff(e);
    }
}
```

I have tried to refactor this to LINQ:

```
var query = 
    from e in elements
    where 
    ( 
        isTable(e.Key)
        && tables.ContainsKey(e.Key)
        && tables[e.Key].Elements
                .Any(subElem => shouldBeIncluded(subElem.Key) )
    ) || (
        !isTable(e.Key)
        && shouldBeIncluded(e.Key)
    )
    select e;
foreach(e in query){
    includedElements.Add(e.Key);
    DoSomeMoreStuff(e);
}
```

What I'm not sure of is the **or** clause here. In my head I need to include `!isTable(e.Key)` to handle the outer `if`/`else if` structure.
Am I thinking right with my refactoring? Are these two code examples resulting in the same logical functionality?

Is it a way I can get away with only one call to `isTable`? As I have it now I need to call it inverted on the other side of the `||`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right. This if `isTable` doesn't have side effects (doesn't do anything but check something) and is deterministic based on the parameters (so calling it twice with e.Key always result in the same value). Still it *could* (it *could* be a premature optimization... Who knows?) probably be better to keep it more similar to the original `if` and use a ternary operator (`? :`) so not to recheck `isTable`

```
var query = 
    from e in elements
    where 
        isTable(e.Key) ? 

            tables.ContainsKey(e.Key) && tables[e.Key].Elements
                .Any(subElem => shouldBeIncluded(subElem.Key) ) 
        :

            shouldBeIncluded(e.Key)
    select e;
```

I'll add that if you hate ternary operators, you could use the `let` keyword:

```
var query = 
    from e in elements
    let isT = isTable(e.Key)
    where 
        ( isT && tables.ContainsKey(e.Key) && tables[e.Key].Elements
            .Any(subElem => shouldBeIncluded(subElem.Key) ) )
            ||
        ( !isT && shouldBeIncluded(e.Key) )
    select e;
```

to cache the isTable(e.Key)

Comment: Great. Although the check on `isTable` does nothing fancy, it is still a call to check if it exists in a dictionary, which can potentioally be expensive if the dictionary is large. Your solution(s) is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The `else if` implies that the `if` condition did not match, so

```
if(A) { 
    if(B) { 
        if(C) { 
            include = true; 
        } 
    } 
}
else if(D) {
    include = true;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(A) { 
    if(B) { 
        if(C) { 
            include = true; 
        } 
    } 
}

if(!A && D) {
    include = true;
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if ((A && B && C) || (!A && D)) {
    include = true;
}
```

which is exactly what you have written in LINQ.

Comment: The question was not really about the boolean logic in the if's, but a way to refactor to LINQ without having to call the `isTable` method twice. Since it is a method, it can potentially be a performance issue if the method is heavy.